# Update oracle query issue with Join

Tags: oracle

I dont understand why its giving Sql Command not properly ended,

```
              Update Table1
                 Set LS.SECU_CHECKER_CODE  = '1000',
                     LS.SECU_CHECKER_DATE  = To_Char(SysDate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),
                     LS.SECU_RECORD_STATUS = 98 
                From Table1 LS
                Join Table2 LS2
                  On LS2.SECC_SECURITY_ID = LS.SECU_SECURITY_ID
               Where LS2.SECC_LIMIT_ID    = '00010101010101';
```

Comment: On a sidenote: Why are you storing the date as a string? You shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for updating from a view is different in Oracle from the syntax you are using. However, you shouldn't even update from a view in your case, because you are not using the other table's content, but merely check for existence of a record for which you should rather use `EXISTS` or `IN`:

```
update table1
set secu_checker_code  = '1000'
  , secu_checker_date  = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmddhh24miss')
  , secu_record_status = 98 
where secu_security_id in
(
  select secc_security_id
  from table2
  where secc_limit_id = '00010101010101'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to update a selection of table 1. You need a where clause.
Possibly something like this:

```
update table1 t1
   set ls.secu_checker_code  = '1000'
      ,ls.secu_checker_date  = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
      ,ls.secu_record_status = 98
 where t1.secu_security_id in (select t2.secc_security_id
                                 from table2 t2
                                where t2.secc_limit_id = '00010101010101');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also working fine

```
UPDATE table1 
   SET (SECU_CHECKER_CODE, 
        SECU_CHECKER_DATE, 
        SECU_RECORD_STATUS) = (
                                Select '1000',
                                       To_Date(SysDate), 
                                       98
                                   From table1
                                   Join table2 
                                     On SECC_SECURITY_ID = SECU_SECURITY_ID
                                  Where SECC_LIMIT_ID    = '00010101010101')
```